# Remove Bitnami Access page and access application directly

Tags: redmine, bitnami

I've installed Redmine using Bitnami stack on port 3000. How can I remove the first page accessed by typing the url (Access BitNami Redmine Stack) and directly configure Redmine on this address?

Currently I need to add /redmine behind url to access redmine. Pls advise.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is for `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` to work, then you could add this in to your htdocs index file (which is probably C:\Program Files\BitNami Redmine Stack\apache2\htdocs\index.html).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        window.location = "redmine/"
    //-->
</script>
```

That will immediately redirect you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should edit the passenger config file in the `/opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/conf/redmine.conf` path like this:

```
#RailsBaseURI /redmine
DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/public
PassengerMinInstances 1
PassengerPreStart http://127.0.0.1
PassengerFriendlyErrorPages off
PassengerDefaultUser daemon
PassengerDefaultGroup daemon

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/public">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  AllowOverride all
  Options -MultiViews
<Directory>
```